# What does Resharper mean by "Object allocation (evident)"?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, resharper

Resharper highlights the new keyword in my code with a hint "Object allocation (evident)".

What does this mean?

[image: Resharper highlighting "Object allocation (evident)"]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[Source](https://github.com/controlflow/resharper-heapview/blob/a0d6ceb49b108c6d6b4a550b703546786fcc1249/ReSharper.HeapView/src/Highlightings/ObjectAllocationHighlighting.cs)

> Highlights object creation expressions where explicit allocation
>   happens.

It means it can be used to notify you about new allocations and thus reduce number of heap allocations in hot paths of your C# program.

Comment: but, how does that help in reducing no. of heap allocation? By making the user aware? or does it optimize the generated assembly?

Comment: @BumbleBee Only highlighting the event, it leaves the user to decide how to reoptimize its code.